# Javascript Facebook SDK Syntax

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the Facebook javascript SDK to allow users of my webpage to update their status. I am getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ," in my login code for my permissions:

```
FB.login(function(response) 
{
    if (response.authResponse) 
    {
        alert('Logged in and accepted permissions!');
    }
}, {scope:'publish_stream', 'offline_access', 'manage_pages'});
```

Any ideas why that would be? I am pretty sure the syntax is correct.

Comment: You are pretty sure, like the rest of the developers in world. We do silly mistakes until someone finds it out for us.

Look at my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing permissions in wrong way,

Use this,

```
FB.login(function(response) 
{
    if (response.authResponse) 
    {
        alert('Logged in and accepted permissions!');
    }
}, {scope:'publish_stream, offline_access,manage_pages'});
```

**Reference:** http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: Ok that removes the error, but now when I run it, the permissions window pops up but it continually waits for www.facebook.com (white box), not sure if that's something I'm doing or not.

Comment: Have you set correct namespace , redirect url in app settings ?

Comment: Yes, site name to www.XXXXXX.com and domain name to XXXXXX.com

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid JS dictionary literal:

`{scope:'publish_stream', 'offline_access', 'manage_pages'}`

If you want those three items as a list under the key `scope`, enclose them in `[]`:

`{scope: ['publish_stream', 'offline_access', 'manage_pages']}`

Comment: This is valid js object literal, but I guess, it wont work for fb. Fb asks for a string in `scope` property (not an array)